# follower system in django "bool is not callable"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a follower system using django and have come accross this issue can someone please help me with it, or give me some suggestions regarding making a follower system with django.

the traceback is as following

> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\Mustafa
>   Lakhani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "D:\sb\blog\views.py" in get
>     186.        if request.user.is_authenticated():
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /user/mustafalakhani/follow Exception
>   Value: 'bool' object is not callable

the code is given below

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='followed_by', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def saveimg(self):
        super().save()

        img=Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height>300 or img.width>300:
            output_size=(300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.saveimg(self.image.path)
```

views.py

```
class UserFollowView(View):
    def get(self, request, username, *args, **kwargs):
        toggle_user=get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact=username)
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            user_profile, created=Profile.objects.get_or_create(request.user)
            if toggle_user in user_profile.following.all():
                user_profile.following.remove(toggle_user)
            else:
                user_profile.following.add(toggle_user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(home)
```

urls.py

```
path('user/<str:username>/follow', UserFollowView.as_view(),name='follow_user'),
```

Comment: The exception message is quite helpful in telling you what the problem is. `user.is_authenticated` is a boolean, not a method. You are trying to call it as a method. Drop the `()`.

Answer (score 4):

In Django 2, `user.is_authenticated` is an attribute, so you you need to drop the `()`

```
request.user.is_authenticated
```

Answer (score 1):

`user.is_authenticated` is a boolean. That it means it can either be `True` or `False`. As it is not a function, nothing is returned when you attempt to call it.

Simply remove the parentheses that indicate that you'd like to call it:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
```